# NodeJSでの return; もしくは return false; の挙動について

Tags: javascript, node.js

例えば以下のコードのように、メソッド以外で`return;`や`retrun false;`を実行するとそこで処理が止まってしまうのはなぜですか？

```
var n = 0;
// 出力される
console.log("hoge");

if ( n == 0 ) return;

// 出力されない
console.log("foo");
```

よろしくお願いします。

### UPDATE Mon 8 June

nodejsでの実行環境になります。

Comment: 文法上のエラーですので`console.log("hoge")`が実行されるかどうかも保障されていないと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もし、Node.jsで実行しているのであれば...
Node.jsではファイルごとに1つの関数としてコンパイルされるため、サンプルコードの`return`文は有効なコードとなります。本来の意味通り、関数の実行を中断して呼び出し元に帰ります。

Comment: そうなんですね。ありがとうございます！もしよろしければNodeJSのこの挙動について書かれたドキュメントなどあれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: むぅ、ドキュメントは見たことがないのですが... Node.js はjsファイルを実行する時とrequireで読み込むとき、[この関数](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/src/node.js#L794-801)でファイルの中身をラップします。これによって、`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ソースコード })(...);`としてコンパイルされます。そして、`require`や`exports`といったお馴染みの変数・関数が引数として与えられて、実行されます。正式なドキュメントに関しては... 知ってる人にパス!!